# Problem registering two instances of IEnumerable<Type>

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have a problem with SimpleInjector and I don't know how to resolve it. I'm getting the following error:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type IMiddleware failed. The constructor of type LogContextMiddleware contains the parameter with name 'controllerTypeExclusionList' and type IEnumerable<Type>, but IEnumerable<Type> is not registered. For IEnumerable<Type> to be resolved, it must be registered in the container. You can use one of the Container.Collection.Register overloads to register a collection of Type types, or one of the Container.Collection.Append overloads to append a single registration to a collection. In case you intend to resolve an empty collection of Type elements, make sure you register an empty collection; Simple Injector requires a call to Container.Collection.Register to be made, even in the absence of any instances. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/collections for more information about registering and resolving collections.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance, my code is:

```
// Log Context Middleware
var controllerTypeLogExclusionList = new List<Type> { typeof(StatusController) };
container.Register<LogContextMiddleware>(
   instanceCreator: () => new LogContextMiddleware(
       controllerTypeExclusionList: controllerTypeLogExclusionList,
   logger: container.GetInstance<ILogger>()),
   lifestyle: Lifestyle.Transient);

// Authorization Middleware
var controllerTypeAuthorizationExclusionList = new List<Type>
{
    typeof(StatusController),
    typeof(PruebaSinAuthController)
};
container.Register<AuthorizationMiddleware<AppToken>>(
   instanceCreator: () => new AuthorizationMiddleware<AppToken>(
       appTokenRepository: container.GetInstance<IAppTokenRepository<AppToken>>(),
       controllerTypeExclusionList: controllerTypeAuthorizationExclusionList,
   logger: container.GetInstance<ILogger>()),
   lifestyle: Lifestyle.Transient);
```

controllerTypeExclusionList in both cases are
`IEnumerable<Type>`

**EDIT 1**:

My code was:

```
var controllerTypeExclusionList = new List<Type> {
   typeof(StatusController),
   typeof(PruebaSinAuthController) };

container.RegisterInstance<IEnumerable<Type>>(controllerTypeExclusionList);
```

With this option both classes share the same list because I'm calling to `container.GetInstance<IEnumerable<Type>>()`

The main problem is that I need different lists for each Middleware. I hope this helps clarify my problem

**EDIT 2**

**LogContextMiddleware** class

```
public class LogContextMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypeExclusionList;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public LogContextMiddleware(
        IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypeExclusionList,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        this.controllerTypeExclusionList = controllerTypeExclusionList;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
```

Thanks @Steven

Comment: Your question is incomplete, because the code sample you are showing does produce the provided error message. The error message implies that Simple Injector is calling the `LogContextMiddleware` constructor (using Auto-Wiring), but in the example you are registering a lambda where your C# code calls the `LogContextMiddleware` constructor. Please turn your question and the code example into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are registering `LogContextMiddleware` using: `container.Register<T>(Func<T>)` where you supply the registration with a lambda expression that calls `new LogContextMiddleware`. This means that Simpe Injector will *not* invoke the constructor itself with *this* registration. So this means that there is some other registration for `LogContextMiddleware`. This is still missing from your question, even after the updates. Again: the error you are getting does *not* match the code you are providing.

Comment: There is no other registration for `LogContextMiddleware` @Steven. As you already said in the answer below, I need to inject specific lists of types in different classes. I don't know how to do this; another option is to Set the controllerTypeExclusionList without IoC. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the your first shown code example works and already solves your problem. That code example *doesn't* reproduce the error you are getting. Your question needs more details, because the problem is not reproducible. As long as this mismatch and your question is incomplete, no one can help you with this. My advise is to try to recreate the problem in an empty console application. There's clearly things going on in your configuration that aren't shown in your question.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, I don't know what you are trying to do but it seems like you picked a terrible way to handle it.